# Should I set up a VPN for these services?

Tags: vpn, access-control, configuration

I'm developing a personal project with a few people. I need to setup Continuous Integration service, Jenkins, version control service, Perforce, repository manager service, Nexus, and a Web server.

My thinking is, that only Web server needs to be hosted on a public network, while all the other services, including Jenkins, Perforce, and Nexus should be accessed only internally, on our local network or using VPN.

Is this a good use case for Virtual Private Network? What's the best practice?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a generic "best practice". Some apps require dev infrastructure with lots of security (eg: air gapped) while others require much less (eg: open source). The open source model is to do run everything on (free) cloud services available to everyone. Can you add some more requirements to your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good use case of using Virtual Private Network? What's the
>   best practice?

It is a broad question and it depends on many factors (size of your team, user locations, network zones, location of DBs, internal network connections among hosts etc).

To put it simply, you should be only exposing your production web server and your other hosts should be only accessible through VPN. You may want to setup an internal dev web server to complete you CI.

Comment: Every open source development app has, by definition, their source open to the public. I assume that you are not saying that they all have it wrong. I think you are making assumptions about the needs of the OP. At this point I don't think we have enough data to provide a good answer. Hopefully the OP will add more info to the question.